# slf4j version incompatibility

Tags: java, gradle, reflection, slf4j

I am trying to use the org.reflections library in my project. I am adding it to the list of my gradle dependencies, but when I run my code I get the following:

```
SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
```

I understand this is because one of my dependencies is using internally a higher version of slf4j that is incompatible with the one that org.reflections is using.

I saw a suggestion to make sure the jar with the older version be included last. how can I do that in Gradle or is there another solutionH

Comment: Why not include the newer version instead?

Comment: from what I understand the org.reflections jar is using the older version. My project and its dependencies is using the new version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way :

```
compile (group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.10'){
    exclude group : "org.slf4j"
}
```

exclude the `slf4j` from your `org.reflections` dependency.

Comment: if I do this, I see an error that intellij does not see the org.reflections.Reflections package

Comment: Mmm, wired it’s suppose to exclude only slf4j

Comment: I am not sure what is happening, I added your code in the project that is imported as a dependency and now it works. If I add it directly in the project It does not see the package. Any idea why? I am going to approve this answer anyway